# WordPress: Responsive featured image with title

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the following code to display a featured image in WordPress. It's working correctly, but I am struggling with `get_the_title()` to display the title of the post within the image and have that adjust correctly when being responsive.

```
echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ).'" style="width:100%; height:auto;">';
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? *I am struggling with `get_the_title()` to display the title of the post within the image and have that adjust correctly when being responsive.* Any visual representation of, *what you want* and *what you get*, with this code is more helpful in understanding the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, ignore the comment about get_the_title. I'm trying to display the featured image and put text within the featured image. I want both to be responsive. For example, the text should be centered within the image and when switching to a different device (desktop to iPhone), the image should shrink and the text should still be centered.

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the image as a background in a div and place the title inside.

```
// you can use get_the_ID() or $post->ID to get the ID of the post

$featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full'); 

<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $featured_img_url;?>);">

   <h2 class="the-title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>

</div>

// Add this to your css
.wrapper{
   position: relative;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-position: center;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
// This will center the text inside
.the-title{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```